Polars-python: Optimal method to check list column elements presence in another list
Is there a more optimal approach to check if the elements in a list dtype column are in another input list?
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {"sets": [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [9, 10]]}
)

df.with_columns(
    (
        pl.col("sets").list.set_intersection([1,7]).list.len() != 0
    ).alias("check")
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬───────┐
│ sets      ┆ check │
│ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ list[i64] ┆ bool  │
╞═══════════╪═══════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ true  │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ true  │
│ [9, 10]   ┆ false │
└───────────┴───────┘


So, you want to check whether any element is in the other list?

Exactly, either in a list or in another (list-type) column. Thanks for your answer below, it is a very interesting approach!

The code snippet you provided looks like idiomatic polars to me. Another approach, could be to evaluate for each element in each of the lists whether it is contained in [1, 7] and, then, use pl.Expr.list.any.
df.with_columns(
    pl.col("sets").list.eval(pl.element().is_in([1, 7])).list.any().alias("check")
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌───────────┬───────┐
│ sets      ┆ check │
│ ---       ┆ ---   │
│ list[i64] ┆ bool  │
╞═══════════╪═══════╡
│ [1, 2, 3] ┆ true  │
│ [1, 2]    ┆ true  │
│ [9, 10]   ┆ false │
└───────────┴───────┘

A tentative performance comparison indicates that pl.Expr.list.set_intersection is slightly faster. Still, if the DataFrames are not huge, the decision can likely be made purely based on readability.

Adding to the nice solution proposed by Hericks, and in case it is useful for others too, the set_intersection() expression can also be used for non-list dtype columns as follows to imitate the behavior of an is_in expression on the objective column:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({"sets": [2, 1, 10], "sets2": [1, 3, 9]})
df.with_columns(
    (
        pl.col("sets")
        .list.set_intersection(pl.concat_list(pl.col("sets2")).flatten().implode())
        .list.len()
        != 0
    ).alias("check")
)

shape: (3, 3)
┌──────┬───────┬───────┐
│ sets ┆ sets2 ┆ check │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ bool  │
╞══════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ 2    ┆ 1     ┆ false │
│ 1    ┆ 3     ┆ true  │
│ 10   ┆ 9     ┆ false │
└──────┴───────┴───────┘


You can use .is_in directly for that: df.with_columns(check = pl.col("sets").is_in("sets2"))

Thanks a lot for the comment! I was thinking on a use case where we need to input either an int, a pl.col() or both, something like
df.with_columns((pl.col("sets").list.set_intersection(pl.concat_list(10, pl.col("sets2")).flatten().implode()) .list.len() != 0).alias("check"))
which I did not manage to make work using pl.Expr.is_in(), but maybe I missed something.
